# winstonjs - log child process stdout / stderr with winston via pipe

Tags: winston

I want to pipe process stderr/stdout into winston and I'm not certainly sure how to do it.

It should be done with something like this:

```js
childProcess.stderr.pipe(winstonLogger.someReadbleInterface)
```

but I cannot find a way. Any clue?